# Why is Bootstrap 4 text-right not working properly?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to make the text in the blue column div align on the right side just like the red div, but text-right does not seem to work.  I also want the letters to keep sticking together like they do now:  [I]|dashboard

[image]

This is my html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 text-right color1setter">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 text-right color2setter">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-md-auto ">
            [I]
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-auto ">
            |
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-auto">
            Dashboard
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try with pull-right

Comment: @ZimSystem I think you are using Bootstrap 3.3.7, But OP wants in Boostrap 4

Answer (score 4):

As your auto columns have no width, they are all bunching on the left of your row - add `ml-auto` (`margin-left: auto`) class to the first auto col and it will push everything to the right:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-right color1setter">
      test
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 text-right color2setter">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-auto ml-auto"> <!-- add ml-auto class here -->
          [I]
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-auto ">
          |
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-auto">
          Dashboard
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example bootply](https://www.bootply.com/BpBPdS06wX#)

[Bootstrap auto-margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins)

Comment: You should probably update docs link to current version: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Comment: @Klooven thanks, done, although to the auto margins section - they've renamed it in the proper document!

Answer (score 0):

Colors to the background of your divs were added so as to show the group staying together, using float right for the group.

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-right color1setter" style="background-color: darkred; color: aliceblue">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-right color2setter" style="background-color: red">
    <div class="row no-gutters" style="float: right;">
      <div class="col-md-auto " style="background-color: violet">
        [I]
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-auto " style="background-color: blueviolet">
        |
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-auto" style="background-color: purple;">
        Dashboard
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```